# Change button image when context menu item is selected

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Can anyone tell me how to change button image when context menu Item is clicked?

I have a button with image and context menu in it. I want to change the image of the button, everytime I click contextmenu item.
With the following piece of code I am able to display contextmenu items on right click. But don't know how to proceed further. 
Can anyone guide me ? 
I tried using command strangely command never got called.

```
  <Button Background="Gray" Name="statusBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red">
            <DockPanel >
                <Image DockPanel.Dock="Top" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ToEnum, Converter={StaticResource EnumToImgConverter}}"  Height="37" Width="72" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,23,1,2">Test</TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Name="ContextMenuName" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Popuplistitems}">
                    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate DataType="MenuItem">
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Message}" Command="{Binding popupListCommand}">
                                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle >
                                            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
                                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                            </Style>
                                 </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                             </MenuItem>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
```

Comment: you say "with the following piece of code." wheres the code?

Comment: Sorry. I updated my post with code

Comment: oh sorry did not read that you were using wpf. Maybe this will help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9b7dc8ed-ea08-4cef-846c-ea50af1ad389/wpf-button-should-change-image-and-have-no-button-look

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.But how to get the selected menuitem ? I have 10 menuitems which are binded in code behind and I need to display different image for each of the selected menuitem. Bear with me as I am new to wpf\mvvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you need to change your MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle to just MenuItem.Style - I believe the ItemContainerStyle is meant for the sub-menuitems that you can place into the MenuItem when you want nested context menus.

I was able to get the content of the button to change with the following code.  I used text content, but it should be easy to swap it out for image content:

The xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ChangeButtonContent.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Height="30" Width="200">
        <Button.Content>
        <DockPanel >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChangingText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DockPanel>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="ContextMenuName">
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding ChangeTextCommand}" Header="ChangeText"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

The Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        ChangingText = "Initial Text";

        ChangeTextCommand = new MyCommand((notUsed) =>
        {
            ChangingText = "Text After Context Menu Click";
        });

    }

    private string _changingText;
    public string ChangingText
    {
        get
        {
            return _changingText;
        }
        set
        {
            _changingText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChangingText");
        }
    }

    public MyCommand ChangeTextCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class MyCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _action;
    public MyCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried out xaml approach. No luck :(

Comment: Command gets called if I try to hardcode the menuitem header as follows: <Button.ContextMenu><ContextMenu Name="popuplist"><MenuItem Header="Testing" Command="{Binding PopupListCommand}"><MenuItem.Style ><Style TargetType="MenuItem"><Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/><Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/></Style></MenuItem.Style></MenuItem></ContextMenu></Button.ContextMenu>

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am able to get this code working with image and hard coded header. If I try to bind header as below it errors out: <Button.ContextMenu><ContextMenu Name="ContextMenuName" ItemsSource="{Binding PopupListData}"><MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}" Command="{Binding ChangeTextCommand}" Header="{Binding Message}" /></DataTemplate></ContextMenu.ItemTemplate></ContextMenu></Button.ContextMenu> but I get the error "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Comment: I am binding this to List<class> obj.

Comment: You are getting that error because you are trying to add items to your context menu by specifying ItemsSource AND explicitly adding MenuItem children.  Those are mutually exclusive options.

Comment: I bind the Command ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=DataContext.ChangeTextCommand}"

Comment: Do you know how to get only one menuitem checked ?

Comment: I do - but you should post that as a separate question on the forum.  I'd be happy to take a look once you do.